# Error got an unexpected keyword argument 'auto_id' en formset Django

Tags: python-3.x, django-forms

Soy muy nuevo en desarrollo y mas aún en Django.
He creado una tabla persona, (matricula, nombre e email) y una tabla peticionario (jefe, peticionario, resp_servicio y resp_aplicacion cada uno de estos es una persona a través de clave foranea).Como los dos últimos son opcionales (el rs y ra) quiero trabajar con FormSet.
El caso es que al cargar este formset de la clase persona me da el siguiente error "Persona() got an unexpected keyword argument 'auto_id'".
He buscado pero no encuentro una solución que entienda (repito, estoy muy perdido), el código es el siguiente:
models.py:`

```
from django.db import models
from recogidaDatos import choices


class Persona(models.Model):
    matricula = models.CharField(max_length=7, verbose_name='Matrícula', unique=True)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Nombre')
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=150,verbose_name='Email')    

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'persona'
        verbose_name_plural = 'personas'
        ordering = ['nombre']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

class Solicitantes(models.Model):
    jefe = models.ForeignKey(Persona, related_name='jefe', verbose_name="Jefe", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    peticionario = models.ForeignKey(Persona, related_name='peticionario', verbose_name="Jefe", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    ra = models.ForeignKey(Persona, related_name='ra', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Responsable aplicación")
    rs = models.ForeignKey(Persona, related_name='rs', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Responsable Servicio")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Solicitantes'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Solicitantes'
        ordering = ['jefe']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.jefe + self.peticionario + self.ra + self.rs`
```

forms.py:

```
    from django import forms
from .choices import *
from .models import *


class FormPersona(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Persona
        exclude = []
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.forms import formset_factory
from .models import *
from .forms import *

# Create your views here.

def recogidaDatos(request):

    PersonasFormset = formset_factory(Persona, extra=4 ,max_num=4)
    personas = PersonasFormset()



    if request.method =='POST':
        personas = PersonasFormset(data=request.POST)
        if  personas.is_valid():   
            pass         
    return render(request,'recogidaDatos/formulario2.html',{'personas':personas})
```

template.py:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}

    {{personas.management_form}}
    <table>
        {% for persona in personas.forms %}
            {{ persona }}
        {% endfor %}
    </table>


    <input name="" id="" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Enviar">
  </form>
```

error:

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
May 20, 2020 - 15:57:38
Django version 3.0.5, using settings 'ComunicacionesApp.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vmorenog\Miniconda3\envs\webProfesional\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 828, in _resolve_lookup   
    current = current[bit]
  File "C:\Users\vmorenog\Miniconda3\envs\webProfesional\lib\site-packages\django\forms\formsets.py", line 74, in __getitem__       
    return self.forms[index]
  File "C:\Users\vmorenog\Miniconda3\envs\webProfesional\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\vmorenog\Miniconda3\envs\webProfesional\lib\site-packages\django\forms\formsets.py", line 137, in forms
    return [
  File "C:\Users\vmorenog\Miniconda3\envs\webProfesional\lib\site-packages\django\forms\formsets.py", line 138, in <listcomp>       
    self._construct_form(i, **self.get_form_kwargs(i))
  File "C:\Users\vmorenog\Miniconda3\envs\webProfesional\lib\site-packages\django\forms\formsets.py", line 175, in _construct_form  
    form = self.form(**defaults)
  File "C:\Users\vmorenog\Miniconda3\envs\webProfesional\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 500, in __init__
    raise TypeError("%s() got an unexpected keyword argument '%s'" % (cls.__name__, kwarg))
TypeError: Persona() got an unexpected keyword argument 'auto_id'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vmorenog\Miniconda3\envs\webProfesional\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner    
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\vmorenog\Miniconda3\envs\webProfesional\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\vmorenog\Miniconda3\envs\webProfesional\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\Escritorio\Comunicaciones_App\ComunicacionesApp\recogidaDatos\views.py", line 19, in recogidaDatos
    return render(request,'recogidaDatos/formulario2.html',{'personas':personas})
  File "C:\Users\vmorenog\Miniconda3\envs\webProfesional\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\vmorenog\Miniconda3\envs\webProfesional\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string 
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "C:\Users\vmorenog\Miniconda3\envs\webProfesional\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render  
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\vmorenog\Miniconda3\envs\webProfesional\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\vmorenog\Miniconda3\envs\webProfesional\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\vmorenog\Miniconda3\envs\webProfesional\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\vmorenog\Miniconda3\envs\webProfesional\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 903, in render_annotated  
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\vmorenog\Miniconda3\envs\webProfesional\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 161, in render     
    values = self.sequence.resolve(context, ignore_failures=True)
  File "C:\Users\vmorenog\Miniconda3\envs\webProfesional\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 670, in resolve
    obj = self.var.resolve(context)
  File "C:\Users\vmorenog\Miniconda3\envs\webProfesional\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 795, in resolve
    value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
  File "C:\Users\vmorenog\Miniconda3\envs\webProfesional\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 836, in _resolve_lookup   
    current = getattr(current, bit)
  File "C:\Users\vmorenog\Miniconda3\envs\webProfesional\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\vmorenog\Miniconda3\envs\webProfesional\lib\site-packages\django\forms\formsets.py", line 137, in forms
    return [
  File "C:\Users\vmorenog\Miniconda3\envs\webProfesional\lib\site-packages\django\forms\formsets.py", line 138, in <listcomp>       
    self._construct_form(i, **self.get_form_kwargs(i))
  File "C:\Users\vmorenog\Miniconda3\envs\webProfesional\lib\site-packages\django\forms\formsets.py", line 175, in _construct_form  
    form = self.form(**defaults)
  File "C:\Users\vmorenog\Miniconda3\envs\webProfesional\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 500, in __init__
    raise TypeError("%s() got an unexpected keyword argument '%s'" % (cls.__name__, kwarg))
TypeError: Persona() got an unexpected keyword argument 'auto_id'
[20/May/2020 15:57:44] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 180395
```

error en el navegador:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] La linea 23 aque se refiere el pantallazo es `{% for persona in personas.forms %}`
Necesito una explicación para niños, jeje.
Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

Me acabo de topar con el mismo error que tu.
No se si sea para todos los casos pero el error era el mismo

```
raise TypeError("%s() got an unexpected keyword argument '%s'" % (cls.__name__, kwarg))
TypeError: Equipment() got an unexpected keyword argument 'auto_id'
```

Al parecer tenia dos modelos el mismo nombre Equipment en diferentes apps. Te recomiendo que busques si en algun otro lado tienes otra clase Persona() en tu codigo